# can we use truncate query in android sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

can we use truncate query in android database?
otherwise can we performing truncate operation using our java code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I have to truncate a table, I simply drop and recreate it.

Documentation ( http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html ):

> When the WHERE is omitted from a DELETE statement and the table being deleted has no triggers, SQLite uses an optimization to erase the entire table content without having to visit each row of the table individually. This "truncate" optimization makes the delete run much faster.

Answer (score 8):

DELETE FROM *tablename*
VACUUM

Ex:

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME);
db.execSQL("VACUUM");
```

Note: this won't reset the row numbering for rows using AUTOINCREMENT.  For that you'll need to drop the table and recreate it.

source: http://phpcode.mypapit.net/how-to-truncate-table-in-sqlite-database/49/

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I used, just for illustration:

```
private static final String TABLE_SCHEMA = "CREATE  TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (\"id\" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , \"runtime\" INTEGER, \"timestamp\" DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TABLE_NAME);

db.execSQL(TABLE_SCHEMA);
```

Answer (score 1):

As WarrenFaith pointed out, I am just giving the code for the logic as in Dec-2019

**In Your Activity/Fragment**

```
// Delete The Temp Table
public static void clearSQLiteTempImagesTable(Context context) {

    // SQLite Variable
    SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    SQLiteHelper dbHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context);
    mDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    mDatabase.beginTransaction();

    try {

        mDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TempImagesContract.tempImagesTable.TABLE_NAME);
        TempImagesContract.createTempImagesTable(mDatabase);

        mDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        mDatabase.endTransaction();
        mDatabase.close();

    }

}
```

**SQLite Helper**

```
public class TempImagesContract {

    public TempImagesContract() {
    }

    // Create Table
    public static void createTempImagesTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        final String SQL_CREATE_TEMP_IMAGES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                                                    tempImagesTable.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                                                    tempImagesTable._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                                                    tempImagesTable.COLUMN_IMAGE_URL + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
                                                    ");";

        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TEMP_IMAGES_TABLE);

    }

    // Define Table
    public static final class tempImagesTable
            implements BaseColumns {

        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "temp_images";
        public static final String COLUMN_IMAGE_URL = "image_url";

    }
}
```